# How to print a string in pure OCaml

Tags: string, printing, ocaml

Can we print a string in Ocaml without using print_string that it imperative function (I don't know if we can say that). I want a function defined in pure Ocaml. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please explain me how to do that or give me a link where they explain that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pure OCaml does not have side-effects. Printing is a side-effect. If you want your program to be pure, build a string. Both `Printf.sprintf` and `^` can help.

If the total amount of text you intend to build in a purely functional fashion is large, use a data structure that scales to larger contents, such as the [rope](https://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/ftp/ocaml/ds/rope.mli.html).

Comment: But what do you mean by build a string?

Comment: @user3036156 Any printing function is imperative. What you can do if you want to program in a purely functional fashion is construct the message you want and return it as the function's result.

Comment: Thanks I see now what do you mean